# mgcv::s(..., bs = "re") results in an error when the NSM3 package is loaded

Tags: r, mgcv

Apparently, `mgcv::s(..., bs = "re")` results in an error when the `NSM3` package is loaded. Below is a demonstrative example.

Load the`mgcv` package and create a data frame used in the example below.

```
library("mgcv") # version 1.8-24
d <- data.frame(
  y = rnorm(100),
  x = rnorm(100),
  f = sample(letters[1:10], 100, replace = TRUE)
)
```

The following works, as expected:

```
gam(y ~ s(x) + s(f, bs = "re"), data = d)
```

Now, load the `NSM3` package and run the same code.

```
library("NSM3") # version 1.12
gam(y ~ s(x) + s(f, bs = "re"), data = d)
```

I then get the following error:

```
Error in model.matrix.formula(form, data) : data must be a data.frame
```

Interestingly (to me), I receive the same error even after `detach`ing the `NSM3` package.

```
detach("package:NSM3", unload = TRUE)
gam(y ~ s(x) + s(f, bs = "re"), data = d) # This results in the same error.
```

Also, the problem occurs even without explicitly loading the `NSM3` package. Using a function in the package with triple colons (`:::`) is sufficient to cause the issue.

```
NSM3:::pSDCFlig(d$y, d$f, method = "Asymptotic")
gam(y ~ s(x) + s(f, bs = "re"), data = d) # Same error
```

The issue appears to be specific to `s(..., bs = "re")` as `s()` itself still works.

```
gam(y ~ s(x), data = d) # No error
```

What exactly is causing this error and is there a way to prevent it while still allowing the use of functions included in the `NSM3` package?